# find minimum from 2 columns in same line

Tags: text-processing, awk

hi I have data file where I need to find minimum (bigger than 0) in columns 6 and 8 and get consequent column 7 or 9

Original data:

```
1003 04 10 2 2 **1172** *2140* 1179 2140
1003 04 14 4 0 1162 2140 **1161** *1640*
1003 04 9 1 1 **1152** 1640 1157 1640
1004 04 5 0 **1190** *2140* 0 0
1004 04 10 1 0 **1184** *2160* 0 0
1004 04 9 1 0 **1171** *1640* 1198 2140
1006 04 10 3 1 **1157** *2140* 1168 1640
1006 04 9 3 1 0 0 **1149** *1640*
1006 04 2 0 0 1171 2160 **1160** *1640*
1007 04 4 0 0 **1199** *2140* 0 0
1007 04 20 3 3 **1164** *2140* 1197 2140
1007 04 7 0 0 0 0 **1185** *2140*
```

Expected output

```
1003 04 10 2 2 1172 2140 
1003 04 14 4 0 1161 1640
1003 04 9 1 1 1152 1640 
1004 04 5 0 1190 2140 
1004 04 10 1 0 1184 2160 
1004 04 9 1 0 1171 1640 
1006 04 10 3 1 1157 2140 
1006 04 9 3 1 1149 1640
1006 04 2 0 0 1160 1640
1007 04 4 0 0 1199 2140 
1007 04 20 3 3 1164 2140 
1007 04 7 0 0 1185 2140
```

Comment: The 4th line lacks a column.

Comment: Please get rid of the `*`s from your sample input/output so we'll have something we can use to test a potential solution against without having to edit it ourselves.

Comment: When you say `bigger than 0` - are you telling us that that value **IS** always bigger than 0 or that it should only be tested **IF** it is bigger than zero or something else? Please [edit] your question to clarify that and add what you have tried yourself so far. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '($8 > 0 && $8 < $6) || ($6 == 0) { $6 = $8; $7 = $9 }; 1' file | cut -d ' ' -f 1-7
1003 04 10 2 2 1172 2140
1003 04 14 4 0 1161 1640
1003 04 9 1 1 1152 1640
1004 04 5 0 1190 2140 0
1004 04 10 1 0 1184 2160
1004 04 9 1 0 1171 1640
1006 04 10 3 1 1157 2140
1006 04 9 3 1 1149 1640
1006 04 2 0 0 1160 1640
1007 04 4 0 0 1199 2140
1007 04 20 3 3 1164 2140
1007 04 7 0 0 1185 2140
```

This overwrites the 6th and the 7th column with the 8th and the 9th columns if the 6th column is zero or if the 8th column is larger than zero and smaller than the 6th column.

The result of the `awk` command is then trimmed to seven columns using `cut`.

Note that the 4th line of input data contains too few columns (it likely lacks its 4th or 5th column), which is why there seems to be an extra `0` in my result compared to the expected result in the question. This is made clearer if we pass the result through `column -t`:

```
1003  04  10  2  2     1172  2140
1003  04  14  4  0     1161  1640
1003  04  9   1  1     1152  1640
1004  04  5   0  1190  2140  0
1004  04  10  1  0     1184  2160
1004  04  9   1  0     1171  1640
1006  04  10  3  1     1157  2140
1006  04  9   3  1     1149  1640
1006  04  2   0  0     1160  1640
1007  04  4   0  0     1199  2140
1007  04  20  3  3     1164  2140
1007  04  7   0  0     1185  2140
```